# Which algorithm is used to solve for an equilibrium in Nordhaus's RICE?

Tags: general-equilibrium, energy-economics

Nordhaus-Yang's paper on the RICE model is available here; see pg 24 for its defining equations. [https://www3.nd.edu/~nmark/Climate/Nordhaus_Yang_AER.pdf](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Enmark/Climate/Nordhaus_Yang_AER.pdf)

In S4 on pg 7, they explain that the solution is based on a theorem of Negishi, based on the second theorem of welfare economics. I'm not sure how this works; which algorithm do they use to solve for an equilibrium (based on the equations on pg 24)? Are there any references which explain the algorithm in detail?

Here's one that I found for Postdam's REMIND model (which is quite different from RICE). https://www.pik-potsdam.de/members/leimbach/nash-technical-1409.pdf

Thanks.